# Can't access my old email in Thunderbird after upgrading to 12.10

Tags: upgrade, thunderbird, email

I was using Thunderbird on 12.04 and upgraded to 12.10 with the option that keeps my current data 3 days ago. When I entered Thunderbird, it asked for account data, but all of the email from the previous version and all the rules I had defined are gone. But my other files like documents and photos are there.

Is there a way I can recover my old email?

Comment: Start by checking the .thunderbird folder in your Home folder (you'll need to press CTRL + H to show hidden files and folders) and see if you find more than one profile folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Thunderbird Greying out and than everafter displaying some of my account setup but none of my mail.  On looking at the mail storage links I noticed that Ubuntu made a huge change that broke all my folder allocations.  I use Ubuntu at home and Portable Thunderbird at work where I use a Windows box. So I store my mail on the portable drive with the PortableApps on it so that I can carry it from home to work and back again. In both systems, Thunderbird points to the same directory on that portable drive.  Ubuntu has changed the way this works as follows:

Instead of: /media/drivename/

In 12.10 it's: /media/username/drivename/

Which means I had to manually edit every folder location in my Thunderbird settings.  What an unmitigated pain!  However it fixed my problem.

See also:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-docs/+bug/1068277

http://linuxforcynics.com/how-to/ubuntu-12-10-broke-my-external-hdd-shares

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your old emails? I'm sure they're stored fully and securely on a remote server (either yahoo or gmail or hotmail)

By reloggin into your account, you should have them all downloaded back onto your PC. I'm sure that won't take long - not even up to 5 minutes to log out and log in.

Sometimes, the long process can be more convenient and 'shorter'

Answer (score 0):

A regular Thunderbird set-up stores everything in /home/%username%/.thunderbird
When navigating to it in Files make sure you go to View-->Show Hidden Files